# linking mingw dll with windows dll

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

I have 3 dll files and 3 corresponding import libraries generated in mingW. I have linked  these 3 dll's in one dll(say main.dll) using LINK. If I open these 3 dll's individually using dependency walker, it shows no error. If I open main.dll i get dependency issues and get the following error:
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Can you give more details how do you link 3 import libraries in one? Do you mean that main.dll depends on these 3 dlls, or you mixed these 3 dlls code in one bigger dll?

Comment: I have one.dll, two.dll and three.dll and the corresponding one.lib, two.lib and three.lib. I am linking these 3 dll's to produce main.dll using link command(e.g: link one.lib two.lib three.lib main.o /out:main.dll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by myself: I got the solution for the above problem. Before linking the dll's, we have to generate the .def files and then link the import libraries. It worked for me. The link provided the solution: http://mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just linked the import libraries together. That's now linking the actual DLLs. Wouldn't work, anyway: the three DLLs each have their own `DllMain`. How do you think `LINK` is going to choose between them ?

Comment: I got the solution for the above problem. Before linking the dll's, we have to generate the .def files and then link the import libraries. It worked for me. The link provided the solution : http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs